# Linux: how are .pc files used when linking against a shared library?

Tags: c, linux

From my knowledge, *.pc files store metadata about shared libraries. Does the linker automatically use these files when linking against a shared library? If so, where does it search for these files?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the linker does not utilize `.pc` files. Those files are for [`pkg-config`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config), which can in turn be used to generate commands to link.